# Pure strategy- Saddle point in a generic matrix

Tags: game-theory

I am studding Game theory. I know that a game can be solved in pure strategy if it admits a saddle point and I know how to find the saddle point, when the matrix has values.

Now I am trying  to understand how can I show that a matrix 4x2 admits a  saddle point for any value of a generic matrix:
$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d\\
a & d\\
c & b   \end{pmatrix} $

Can someone help me on this:

Comment: You might start by writing down the conditions for, say, the top left entry to be a saddle point.  The other cases are similar.  Do they cover all possibilities?

Comment: Should I do: If a>= b and a<c so a is a saddle point and the game admits a pure strategy? and then do it for all entreis of the matrix?

Comment: Draw the movement diagram/best response arrows. You'll find that it's impossible to avoid having a square with all incoming arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b \ge d$, you can eliminate the rows with $d$ in column $2$.

But then, once that's done, column $2$ has equal values, so one of the two remaining rows can be eliminated.

So now just one row, with $2$ columns.

But then one column can be eliminated.

So now just a $1\times 1$ game.

Thus, an optimal pure strategy is given by the row and column, respectively, in the original matrix, corresponding to the remaining cell in the $1\times 1$ matrix.

Since neither player can do better by any change, it must yield a saddle point.

The reasoning for the case $d \ge b$ is analogous.

The key idea is this: By removing a row or column which is weakly or strongly dominated, the new game still has at least one of the original pure-strategy saddle points if there was one originally, and can't add any new pure-strategy saddle points that weren't there originally.

Comment: I understood what you did but I don't understand how by doing this we can show that the game admits a pure strategy ( saddle point). Can you clarify? thanks.

Comment: I edited in an explanation.

Comment: Perhaps test it by trying some numbers, say $(a,b,c,d)=(1,2,3,4)$, to see how it works.

Comment: I thought I needed to show a case analysis for each case ( 4 cases in total I think) but i will  use values to try to understand, thank you for your help.

Comment: Testing with values is just a test, not a proof. In the answer I posted, I showed that an optimal pure strategy exists, and showed how to find one, so no need for an exhaustive case by case analysis.

Comment: so, showing that there is one saddle point for any value of a,b,c,d, the game admits a solution in pure strategies and it is not necessary to show for all cases

Comment: Yes, as long as the argument starts with unknown $a,b,c,d$. But note: I did consider two cases: $b \ge d$, and $d \ge b$.

Comment: The others are trivial I assume.Thanks

Comment: Well, the case $d \ge b$ uses the same logic.